# Turn Sub-Object Code (raycast & mouse click & sub-objects)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Game characters are going somewhere that is clicked with the mouse
My problem :  the code only works over a GameObject. I want to use one in the ground in the box, it can not. 
     [image]

I use a line of code :

```js
public GameObject obj;
void Update() {
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        RaycastHit rayHit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (obj.collider.Raycast (ray, out rayHit, Mathf.Infinity)) {
            transform.position = rayHit.point;
            renderer.material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

Map as the only model so I need to do. prevents me from making changes to my map
I need to call the individual sub-objects. but I could not.

Translating google translate :)

Comment: When you say ground you mean terrain, as in the Unity terrain which has height maps?

Comment: no, platform style game will be. I will not use height map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayHit)`. This will raycast from your screen into the world. Then you can check the type of the object:

```
if (rayHit.collider.GetType() == typeof(YourTypeHere))
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: if (obj.collider.Raycast (ray, out rayHit, Mathf.Infinity)) changed if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayHit)) ,                               but now every object can be clicked :)